# Facebook Realtime Updates - Dispute - Response

Tags: facebook, real-time-updates, facebook-payments

Noobish question: Are you supposed to respond to realtime updates (RTUs) somehow? Keep getting RTUs on the same dispute which FB has already refunded. So, should one echo something in the RTU callback? Just been through all the documentation I can find (again) and can't seem to find anything on response.

Comment: It should not be nessecary as long as you provide the challenge in the callback. That should be enough to notify facebook that the update was receieved.

Comment: Ehm, but ups! Isn't this only relevant for adding subscriptions? From the guide: 

"Note that the hub.mode, hub.challenge and hub.verify_token parameters are not sent again once the subscription has been confirmed."

So, doesn't seem to be a challenge to echo (indeed no such thing in the post.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to return a 200. The content type or response body do not matter. Anything else results in Facebook retrying the callback until a 200 is received, so you'll get lots of spam