# What response should my endpoint give to the facebook RealTtime Update post request?

Tags: facebook, real-time-updates

what should my server response to the facebook RealTtime Update post request to indicate that the RTU request is handled successfully, I have read the docs for couple times but I cannot find the answer. I am kind of frustrated, looking for your answer.

Comment: Have you read this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/#yourcallbackserver there's notes in there about responses and verification

Comment: yes, I have read the docs, but it only describes about the post request and not what should be returned to facebook

Answer (score 0):

Duplicated question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18873636/facebook-realtime-updates-dispute-response)

On GET request from facebook you should just echo $_GET['hub_challenge']

On POST request from Facebook:

1. If your page responded with Status Code:200 OK - facebook thinking that everything OK
2. If something went wrong and you've sent not 200/OK - facebook will try to resend it later